# Restricting Hibernate Query By Max Date of a Related Object

Tags: hibernate

I have a Shelf class that has many Box classes and the Box class has many Specimen classes. In the Specimen class is a property of catalogDate.

What I'm trying to do is find all Shelves where the max catalogDate is of a given date.

How can I perform the necessary query? I've tried several approaches, but nothing I can find actually performs the same feat.

At best I can project the max of all Specimen instances, but, again, all from the beginning on time.

**EDIT** I can perform what I want via SQL

```
  select shelf.id
        ,max(specimen.catalogDate)
   from shelf_tbl shelf
   inner join box_tbl box
   on shelf.id = box.shelf_id
   inner join specimen_tbl specimen
   on box.specimen_id = specimen.id
   group by shelf.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use joins. If you already have mapped the relations you can write a query like this:

```
select 
       shelf,
       max(specimen.catalogDate) 
from 
   Shelf as shelf join 
   shelf.box as box join 
   box.specimen as specimen
```

And you should add a group by clause with all the properties of Shelf

If you want the self with the newest specimen catalogDate you should add

```
where specimen.catalogDate = (select max(catalogDate) from Specimen)
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with Criteria?

Comment: This only gives me the specimen where date. I need to find a shelf by the newest specimen in the box.

Comment: In Criteria API you can do the joins with Criteria.createAlias
'self.box as box' looks like criteria.createAlias("box", "box")